# Searching fields in Group module

Tags: 8, entities, search, group

I cannot figure out how I can be able to search the fields(set as a new content type) in the Group module.

For example, I created Groups(Group-Shop, Group-Salon, etc) under Group-Type-A with 3 fields containing:

- Name: J-Shop
- Type of Shop: Motor Shop
- Address: Chicago (uses geolocation)

After I added more data, I wanted to be able to search an item (Motor) and ALL related results should have shown up on the map (address of each items).

I've tried using a view with filter *group content*, but of course it would only search for related results (text) and clicking on the item/name would point me to the detailed info. I was looking to filtering/searching via Address/Geolocation of each group.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question. Its all in the view settings.

First, I changed the format from unsorted list of items/groups to Geolocation - CommonMap and modified its settings. This is to display all groups in a single map(A simple solution that I should have noticed at first).

Second, I added all fields needed to be displayed in a group in the map.

Lastly, I added desired filter(this is to search for a group).